# How to subtract today's date (current date) from delivery date SQL Query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that has current date and delivery date. I want to minus due date from current date and want to save only days left in dbtable

```
SELECT clientId, 
       curentDate, 
       deliveryDate DATEDIFF(day,-(deliveryDate) CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Days_Left
FROM  dbo.tblorder
```

e.g:

- today date `12/1/2014`
- delivery date `20/1/2014`
- days left `8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look in [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28sql.100%29.aspx) for examples on how to use `DATEDIFF`?

```
SELECT clientId, currentDate, deliveryDate, 
  Days_Left = DATEDIFF(DAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, deliveryDate) 
FROM dbo.tblorder;
```

Comment: this give an error
DeliveryDate is a Filed in My tblorder and Days Left_left is not a Field

Comment: Oh my God there was spelling mistake
i got it Now it's Worked Thanks Alot

Comment: @user3257950 Sorry, I corrected `currentDate` but introduced my own typo in `deliveryDate`.